# Magento - Best way to build two catalogs and/or product types?

Tags: magento, root, catalog

We have 2 types of products....

Product Type 1: Will be purchased as a normal product
Product Type 2: Customers will have to contact us for more info.

What's the best way to build this in Magento?  Two store views? Or should we write some logic to differentiate products?  Any other advice, recommendations, or resources is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For products with type 2 , you can do following,

1.Make a product attribute, say, getinfo and make it as yes/no.

2.By default set it as no, for products of type 2 set as yes.

3.Keep type2 products Out of Stock , and for addtocart button replace with more info, click of which you could trigger a form to capture info and save it in ypur db